# when hovering, after changing the top pf element trigger mouseleave()

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="butterfly-container">
    <div class="butterfly-circle-border"></div>
    <div class="butterfly-img">
        <img src="assets/img/1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="butterfly-content">
        <h3>The Title</h3>
        <p>This is a descripton for this title and more ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my **Javascript/Jquery Code**:

```
$(function(){

$(".butterfly-circle-border").bind({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).next(".butterfly-img").addClass("butterfly-img-down");
        $(this).next(".butterfly-img").next(".butterfly-content").addClass("butterfly-content-top");
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).next(".butterfly-img").removeClass("butterfly-img-down");
        $(this).next(".butterfly-img").next(".butterfly-content").removeClass("butterfly-content-top");
    }
});

});
```

My problem is when I mouse enter the circle The top of other div's change, and it trigger the mouseleave(). And it doesn't work as I expect.I need hovering make the image goes down and content goes up and on mouseleave it goes viseversa. What should I do?
Here is the link for demo http://design.atousadarabi.ir/mouseovereffect/BlueButterfly/

Comment: butterfly-circle-border is an empty div?

Comment: yes it has height and width and dashed border as you see. At first it wasn't like this but I thought If I do so mouseleave() does well. But it didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new script:

```
$(".butterfly-container").bind({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).children(".butterfly-img").addClass("butterfly-img-down");
        $(this).children(".butterfly-img").next(".butterfly-content").addClass("butterfly-content-top");
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).children(".butterfly-img").removeClass("butterfly-img-down");
        $(this).children(".butterfly-img").next(".butterfly-content").removeClass("butterfly-content-top");
    }
});
```

and it worked. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind event on "butterfly-container".

Comment: Thanks alot.Yes it did